# SomeSite node.js

Tags: node.js, cookie, express

Пишу чат. На фронту используется React.js, а на сервере правит Node.js & Express & MongoDB. Может не самый лучше бэкенд, но всё-же. Я когда делал авторизацию на localhost - всё норм работало, и авторизированы куки были, и добавлялись они, и всё всё ок было, но как только решил провести закрытое бета тестирование, и залил сервер на хостинг, то у меня как не странно начались проблемы с авторизацией, я начал копать код, там в итоге ничего не нашёл, зашёл в браузер, начал следить что там да как, и вижу вот прилетает варнинг: [image: варнинг]

и в итоге - куки не ставиться, а авторизация вообще не работает.

Comment: Посмотрите куда обращается ваш фронт и где на самом деле бек енд. Думаю там у вас настройки на ваш локальный а нужно на продакшн сервер

Comment: @AzizUmarov как раз таки, с апишкой всё ок, и обращение идёт к продакшн версии.

Comment: покажи тогда какие заголовки отдаёт сервер на запрос авторизации